# What is the equivalent to b'string' on a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to encode a string of text before using it, but the only problem is it is a variable and all I know is that normally I would use b'string'.  I assume I would use variable.encode(), but what encoding would I use?

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood the issue and Christian's answer helped me realize what was going on.  Thanks to everyone for helping.

Comment: are you using python 2.7 or python 3.+?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that.  I'm using 2.7

Comment: are you worried about porting your script to python 3?

Comment: Not really worried about porting it to python 3, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to decide which encoding to use. You can either go with UTF-8 as a sensible default, or infer the encoding from the environment.

The environment can be, for example:

- The Content-Type header in HTTP connections
- The LANG/LC_CTYPE variables on UNIX systems
- The [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) function

You can then transform your Unicode variable into a bytes string via [`var.encode(encoding)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

Also check out the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Oh thank you, I completely misunderstood the issue I had and this fixed it.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

#### You dont have to do anything to encode a variable like `b'string'` because its ignored by `python 2.7`. Its used to encode strings as bytes in `python 3.3`.

I learned this from [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/2259303) by NPE which explains this in more detail:

> To quote [the python 2.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):
>
> > A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in
> >     Python 2; it indicates that the
> >     literal should become a bytes literal
> >     in Python 3 (e.g. when code is
> >     automatically converted with 2to3). A
> >     'u' or 'b' prefix may be followed by
> >     an 'r' prefix.
>
> The [python 3.3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) states:
>
> > Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only
> >     contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
> >     must be expressed with escapes.

The flask error is an issue caused becuase the string is not encoded in UTF-8.

Encode it like so:

```
your_string = your_string.encode('utf8')
```

For more details on this issue, look at the reported github issue [here](https://github.com/socketubs/leselys/issues/87).

Comment: Well that's odd, because I'm having serious problems in my Flask application as a result.  When I try to use bcrypt without adding the b in front of the string, I get a server 500 error.  Obviously, this gives me a problem when using bcrypt on input given by the user.  The error I'm getting in Flask says "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"

Comment: @Zaphod flask expects a utf-8 for its parameters. please see my updated answer